# How to change the anchor:hover anchor:visited properties in JavaScript? Is it even possible?

Tags: javascript, html

In HTML I'm trying to change the hover and visited color property/attribute of an anchor tag using JavaScript.

Here is my code that doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script>
      function changeAttributes() {
        document.getElementById("idA"):hover.style.color = "ccffcc";
        document.getElementById("idA"):visited.style.color = "ffcccc";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="changeAttributes();">
    <a id="idA" href="#">Target text</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, I think you need to understand more about js programming language, its syntax, Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just use CSS for this

```
#ida:hover {
   color: #ccffcc;
}
```

If you really want to use javascript I think you should use the `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` events

```
<a 
  id="idA" 
  href="#" 
  onMouseOver="this.style.color='#ccffcc'"  
  onMouseOut="this.style.color='initial'">
      Target text
</a>
```

Still would highly recommend handling these pseudo events with CSS

Comment: So I think a style sheet is needed to do it? I think it cannot be done dynamically with javascript, like in my attempt in the main question?

Comment: @GraemeJensz updated answer for javascript